# Scanning for fresh wallets and deployer connections

Tags: erc-20, chaindata

My main goal is to listen for fresh wallets buying launches of a erc 20 token. We all know fresh wallets (funded from a central exchange) could be created by insiders or friends of developers. Or quickly seeing information of connections to a deployer even if it's multiple hops away. How would I gather this information with Js, jupyter and excel spreadsheet.

Please and thank you for answering my questions. Have a nice day.

Comment: DId you try BigQuery? For fresh wallet the nonce should be zero, or very low.

Comment: I have not thank you very much. Will give it a try and let you know sir.